# Rails: Add Mongoid Document to Temp Store for use in File Export Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am attempting to allow a user to pick rows from a table and add each record to an "export list". This export list is another table which displays the records selected by the user. There is then an option to export to a file..

I am stuck on getting the user selected document ID and displaying it in a separate table.

I have this setup:

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :scenarios do
    collection do
      get :call_copy
      get :export
    end
  end
end
```

Scenarios Controller:

```
class ScenariosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_scenario, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :all_scenarios, only: [:index, :create, :update]
  respond_to :html, :js
  ...
  def index
    @scenarios = if params[:submitter].blank? && params[:application].blank? && params[:pillar].blank? && params[:test_type].blank? && params[:begin_date].blank? && params[:end_date].blank? && params[:search_text].blank?
               Scenario.all.order_by(created_at: :desc)
             else
               Scenario.search_text(params)
             end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  ...
  def export
    @scenario = Scenario.find(params[:id])
    @export_scenarios ||= []
    @export_scenarios << @scenario

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Index.js.erb:

```
$('#export_class').html("<%= j (render 'export', export_scenarios: @export_scenarios) %>")
```

Index.html.erb:

```
<Table>
...
    <li><%= link_to 'Export', export_scenarios_path(id: scenario), remote: true %></li>
...
</table>

<div id="export_class">
  <%= render 'export', export_scenarios: @export_scenarios %>
</div>
```

_Export.js.erb:

```
$('#export_class').html("<%= j (render 'export', export_scenarios: @export_scenarios) %>")
```

_Export.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="max-height: 800px; overflow: scroll;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Scenario Name</th>
    <th>Scenario Body</th>
    <th>Options</th>
    <th colspan="8"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% export_scenarios.each do |scenario| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.scenario_name %></td>
      <td class="text-left"><%= scenario.scenario_body %></td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= submit_tag "Export!", type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right", :name => nil %>
```

Comment: "I am stuck" what does it mean? any error? the html is not right? what should happen and is not happening?

Comment: My exports table does not fill with any of the selected scenarios. The line: `<% export_scenarios.each do |scenario| %>` is nil in the export.html.erb. I would expect `@export_scenarios` to be populated with scenario objects as the user selects them with the export link in the main table.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the scenarios with:

```
render partial: 'export', locals: {export_scenarios: @export_scenarios}
```

Note the `locals` key (EDIT: and the `partial`).

Comment: In _export.html.erb:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `export_scenarios' for #<#<Class:0x00000000095e13f8>:0x00000000095ac360>
Did you mean?  export_scenarios_url):
    12:   </tr>
    13:   </thead>
    14:   <tbody>
    15:   <% export_scenarios.each do |scenario| %>

Comment: sorry, you are rendering a partial, it should be render partial

Comment: I've made the change, export scenarios are still nil in export.html.erb. Do I need to have the lines: `$('#export_class').html("<%= j (render partial: 'export', locals: {export_scenarios: @export_scenarios}) %>")` in both index.js.erb and export.js.erb?

Comment: I want to say my issue now stems from the index page being rendered first, the controller calls the index method, the index page calls the render export.html.erb partial, but no where in there has @exported_scenarios been passed to index. I need to bridge them somehow..

Comment: You can do `locals: {export_scenarios: @scenarios}` on your index view.

Comment: Then the export list is filled with all of the scenarios, I want it blank to start.

Comment: then assign an empty array instead of @scenarios, come one man, are you even trying to understand what's going on there? because it doesn't look like that